# Python type hints: How to specify file pointer as an argument?

Tags: python-3.x, types

I'm writing a function that takes a file pointer as an argument and writes to it. And I want to add a type hint to that argument:

```
def write_some_stuff(fp: _io.TextIOWrapper):
    ...
```

`_io.TextIOWrapper` is what `type(open(...))` gives me.

Is there something else I should use?

Comment: What aspects of the file interface does your function care about? For example would any `Iterable[str]` suffice?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The function needs to be able to write to it. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `typing` module, which was introduced in Python 3.5:
[`typing.TextIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TextIO) fits best in this case.

> Generic type `IO[AnyStr]` and its subclasses `TextIO(IO[str])` and `BinaryIO(IO[bytes])` represent the types of I/O streams such as returned by `open()`.

In your example:

```
from typing import TextIO

def write_some_stuff(fp: TextIO):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be a little more generic and allow any file object that is in text mode (i.e. `read()` returns Unicode strings), you probably want to hint that you take an `io.TextIOBase` argument. That will allow instances of `io.StringIO` in addition to the more common `io.TextIOWrapper` instances.

You also don't need the underscore on the `io` module's name, even if you stick with `TextIOWrapper`. The regular `io` module imports all relevant types from the `_io` module into its own namespace.